# Need some help deciphering a line of assembler code, from .NET JITted code

Tags: c#, assembly, jit, access-violation

In a C# constructor, that ends up with a call to `this(...)`, the actual call gets translated to this:

```
0000003d  call        dword ptr ds:[199B88E8h]
```

What is the DS register contents here? I know it's the data-segment, but is this call through a VMT-table or similar? I doubt it though, since `this(...)` wouldn't be a call to a virtual method, just another constructor.

I ask because the value at that location seems to be bad in some way, if I hit F11, trace into (Visual Studio 2008), on that call-instruction, the program crashes with an access violation.

The code is deep inside a 3rd party control library, where, though I have the source code, I don't have the assemblies compiled with enough debug information that I can trace it through C# code, only through the disassembler, and then I have to match that back to the actual code.

The C# code in question is this:

```
public AxisRangeData(AxisRange range) : this(range, range.Axis) {
}
```

Reflector shows me this IL code:

```
.maxstack 8
L_0000: ldarg.0 
L_0001: ldarg.1 
L_0002: ldarg.1 
L_0003: callvirt instance class DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisRange::get_Axis()
L_0008: call instance void DevExpress.XtraCharts.Native.AxisRangeData::.ctor(class DevExpress.XtraCharts.ChartElement, class DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase)
L_000d: ret
```

It's that last call there, to the other constructor of the same class, that fails. The debugger never surfaces inside the other method, it just crashes.

The disassembly for the method after JITting is this:

```
00000000  push        ebp  
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  sub         esp,14h 
00000006  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000009  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx 
0000000c  cmp         dword ptr ds:[18890E24h],0 
00000013  je          0000001A 
00000015  call        61843511 
0000001a  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
0000001d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
00000020  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
00000023  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 
00000026  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
00000029  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000002b  call        dword ptr ds:[1889D0DCh]   // range.Axis
00000031  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax 
00000034  push        dword ptr [ebp-14h] 
00000037  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-10h] 
0000003a  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
0000003d  call        dword ptr ds:[199B88E8h]   // this(range, range.Axis)?
00000043  nop              
00000044  mov         esp,ebp 
00000046  pop         ebp  
00000047  ret
```

Basically what I'm asking is this:

- What the purpose of the `ds:[ADDR]` indirection here? VMT-table is only for virtual isn't it? and this is constructor
- Could the constructor have yet to be JITted, which could mean that the call would actually call through a JIT shim? I'm afraid I'm in deep water here, so anything might and could help.

---

**Edit**: Well, the problem just got worse, or better, or whatever.

We are developing the .NET feature in a C# project in a Visual Studio 2008 solution, and debugging and developing through Visual Studio.

However, in the end, this code will be loaded into a .NET runtime hosted by a Win32 Delphi application.

In order to facilitate easy experimentation of such features, we can also configure the Visual Studio project/solution/debugger to copy the produced dll's to the Delphi app's directory, and then execute the Delphi app, through the Visual Studio debugger.

Turns out, the problem goes away if I run the program outside of the debugger, but during debugging, it crops up, every time.

Not sure that helps, but since the code isn't slated for production release for another 6 months or so, then it takes some of the pressure off of it for the test release that we have soon.

I'll dive into the memory parts later, but probably not until over the weekend, and post a followup.

Comment: Can you find out which address is actually pointed by ds:[199B88E8h] and disassemble it?

Comment: It's an address stored at that place, and that address points to unmapped memory, hence the access violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data segment is where compilers usually put global variables in and where the Import Address Table resides.

```
00000029  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000002b  call        dword ptr ds:[1889D0DCh]
```

The first line is actually a null-check, which eventually raises a `NullReferenceException` if the pointer located in the ECX register is invalid.

The `callvirt` MSIL instruction must do the null-check before invoking the actual method. That being said, we can safely assume that these two lines of assembly code have the following MSIL code representation:

```
class DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisRange::get_Axis()
```

And the commented assembly code:

```
00000026  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8]      // store the pointer to the 'range' in ECX
00000029  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx        // null-check
0000002b  call        dword ptr ds:[1889D0DCh]   // range.get_Axis()
00000031  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax    // store the result in a local variable
00000034  push        dword ptr [ebp-14h]        // push the result onto a stack
00000037  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]    // this variable was previously loaded with the 'range' pointer
0000003a  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]    // here seems to be stored the actual 'this' pointer
0000003d  call        dword ptr ds:[199B88E8h]   // call the this(...) ctor
```

It's unclear to me why it's crashing, have you tried looking up the contents of the memory location (`DS:[199B88E8h]`)?

Comment: Yes, and I'll post the values I see from the various call-instructions tomorrow. Suffice to say that it looks odd, compared to all the others (I stopped on each call-instruction leading up to this point). The faulty one is the only one with a non-zero first digit.